# Ear To The Ground

Tags: grammar-choice

I'm trying to correctly write "Ear to the ground" in latin for a logo I'm creating.
"Aurem ad Terram"? 
"Aurem in Terra"?
Are either of these correct?
Something else? 
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have asked two unrelated questions in one. It's better to ask only one at a time, so the system works as intended. You can ask separate questions separately, but in this case you can probably just edit your question to delete the second part as it has already been answered. I don't have the time for it now, but I can try to answer your remaining question tomorrow.

Comment: Joonas Ilmavirta, I edited out the second question. Thanks for the heads up. If you can answer my first question when you get a chance, it will be super appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I cleaned up comments related to the now-deleted second part of the question. If anyone thinks the comments should be restored, just let me know or raise a flag. BRNDO: I hope you stick around and ask more questions (and take a look at our [tour]). We're always glad to have new people with an interest in Latin.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you use it, but I think *auris ad terram* is a good phrase with *auris* suitably declined.
For example:

> I hold my ear to the ground so I can hear the train.
> *Aurem ad terram teneo ut tramen audiam.*
>
> With my ear held against the ground, I heard the train.
> *Aure ad terram posita tramen audivi.*

The preposition *ad* has [a huge amount of uses](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=ad&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
I did not find a perfect match (other than II.B.1.c for compounds), but I think this is the most natural preposition here.

Comment: Joonas, Thank you! Much appreciated. "AURIS AD TERRAM" it is.